# Cannot access plugin-addons

Tags: heroku

Hey i have a problem with deploying an app, when i try to deploy he app i get this error

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Using buildpack: heroku/nodejs
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  14.x
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
       
       Resolving node version 14.x...
       Downloading and installing node 14.16.0...
       Using default npm version: 6.14.11
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules
       npm ERR! @heroku-cli/plugin-addons not accessible from heroku
       
       npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
       npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.fHOrI/_logs/2021-03-24T14_04_47_335Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed
       
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
       
       If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
       https://help.heroku.com/
       
       Love,
       Heroku
       
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

Why can it not access plugins that the deploy is generating? in the node_module folder

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error, and I fixed it by running an npm install on the specific library I was missing. I would try reinstalling Heroku CLI, and then npm install again. If you're missing a specific package, then try reinstalling it.

For reference I had this error:

`Installing dependencies`

`Installing node modules`

`npm ERR! ws not accessible from @heroku-cli/plugin-ci`

And I fixed it by running `npm install ws` for the web sockets plugin.